# validate one combination input value not to be equal to another combination input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my table that have 4 input in one row :

```
<tr>
  <td><input type=text name='section[]' class='section'></td>
  <td><select name='finish[]' class='finish'>............</select></td>
  <td><select name='hrd[]' class='hrd'>............</select></td>
  <td><input type=text name='length[]' class='length'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type=text name='section[]' class='section'></td>
  <td><select name='finish[]' class='finish'>............</select></td>
  <td><select name='hrd[]' class='hrd'>............</select></td>
  <td><input type=text name='length[]' class='length'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type=text name='section[]' class='section'></td>
  <td><select name='finish[]' class='finish'>............</select></td>
  <td><select name='hrd[]' class='hrd'>............</select></td>
  <td><input type=text name='length[]' class='length'></td>
</tr>
...
...
...
```

What i need to do is to validate the combination inputs in each row not to be equal with another row using jquery.

```
//Wrong example:

row 1: section=>0001; finish=>A; hrd=>12; length=>2000
row 2: section=>0001; finish=>A; hrd=>12; length=>2000 //it is wrong because the combination already exist in row 1 or another row

//they have to be like this:

row 1: section=>0001; finish=>A; hrd=>11; length=>2000
row 2: section=>0001; finish=>A; hrd=>12; length=>2000 //different hrd
row 3: section=>0001; finish=>B; hrd=>12; length=>2000 //different finish
.... //at least there are one different input
```

I'm using name in array because I have a function to add another new row with the same format and i need to pass each value with POST method.

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var match = false;
var rows = $("tr");
for (var i = 0; !match && i < rows.length-1; i++) {
    var section = $(".section", rows[i]).val(),
        finish = $(".finish", rows[i]).val(),
        hrd = $(".hrd", rows[i]).val(),
        length = $(".length", rows[i]).val();
    for (var j = i+1; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if ($(".section", rows[j]).val() == section &&
            $(".finish", rows[j]).val() == finish &&
            $(".hrd", rows[j]).val() == hrd &&
            $(".length", rows[j]).val() == length) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (match) {
    alert ("Rows must all be different");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Rj23F/2/)

Comment: Ok i will try it and give a feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Works for me, see the fiddle demo.

Comment: yeah. There's something wrong with my code. i'm kinda confused with my code right now. I will fix my code. Thanks a lot barmar.